# expect script has erroneous characters

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

My script ssh's into an HP switch and makes an interface change. I cannot figure out what is causing the erroneous characters in output (see bold).

My script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@switch
expect {
        "password:" { send "passwd\r" ; exp_continue }
        "Press any key to continue" { send " \r" ; exp_continue }
        "240#" { send "conf t\r" }
}
expect {
        "(config)#" { send "int 8\r" }
}
expect {
        "(eth-8)#" { send "enable\r" }
}
expect {
        "(eth-8)#" { send "wr mem\r" }
}
expect {
        "(eth-8)#" { send "end\r" }
}
expect {
        "#" { send "logout\r" }
}
expect eof
```

See erroneous output below:
**;209R** & **;209R^C**

```
user@user-site:/config/scripts$ ./test_disable.exp
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@switch
========= WARNING: Unauthorized access to this system is forbidden 
and will be prosecuted by law. By accessing this system, you agree 
that your actions may be monitored if unauthorized usage is suspected.
===

user@switch's password:
Press any key to continue
Your previous successful login (as user) was on 2016-11-18 14:30:54
from <ip removed>
swtch-16-57-240#
swtch-16-57-240# conf t
swtch-16-57-240(config)# int 8;209R
swtch-16-57-240(eth-8)# enable
swtch-16-57-240(eth-8)# wr mem
swtch-16-57-240(eth-8)# end
swtch-16-57-240# logout
Do you want to log out [y/n]? y
Connection to switch closed by remote host.
Connection to switch closed.
user@user-site:/config/scripts$ ;209R^C
user@user-site:/config/scripts$
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be a munged control sequence?  The only vt100 sequence that ends with R is:

```
Cursor position report        CPR        ESC [ Pl ; Pc R
```

where `Pl` and `Pc` are integers for the Line and Column number of the cursor position (see http://www.vt100.net/docs/vt102-ug/appendixc.html).

The easy solution may be to run ssh like:

```
set env(TERM) dumb
spawn env TERM=dumb ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@switch
```

and the harder way involves stripping the escape sequences somehow.
also try changing `dumb` to `vt100` (what is it set to currently?)

Comment: The 'easy solution' still causes erroneous output. I'll investigate stripping esc seq. Any other input is appreciated.

Comment: You should see what happens if you send your expect script control sequences.  `ssh` into localhost and run a script that echos output similar to the router and also echoes escape sequences like CPR.

Comment: there is a program called vttest that you may be helpful in this situation.